# Wordpress Editor text tab design issue?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I tried the Wp_editor in wordpress for the visual tab is working fine and the text tab is getting list order.

```
 <?php
                                        $settings = array(
                                                        'textarea_name' => 'message1',
                                                         'media_buttons' => true,
                                                        'tinymce' => array(
                                                        'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'formatselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,' .
                                                        'bullist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter' .
                                                        ',justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|' .
                                                        ',spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv'
                                                            )
                                                        );
                                        wp_editor( '', 'content', $settings );
                                                                            ?>
```

[image]

Also For the Visual Editor it should be appear like this
[image]

I don't Know what happen to the wordpress editor.

Any Suggestion would be great.

Comment: do you get any js errors?

Comment: No I didn't get any js error only the alignment is to be look like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did as My Own. That the Problem is that code is inside the table . Finally here is the solution that i did

```
<table>      <tr class="form-field">
            <th valign="top" scope="row">
                <label for="subject"><?php _e('Subject')?></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input id="subject1" name="subject1" type="text" style="width: 95%" value=""
                       size="50" class="code" placeholder="<?php _e('')?>" required>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr class="form-field">
            <th valign="top" scope="row">
                <label for="message1"><?php _e('Message')?></label>
            </th>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
     <?php
                                            $settings = array(
                                                            'textarea_name' => 'message1',
                                                             'media_buttons' => true,
                                                            'tinymce' => array(
                                                            'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'formatselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,' .
                                                            'bullist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter' .
                                                            ',justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|' .
                                                            ',spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv'
                                                                )
                                                            );
                                            wp_editor( '', 'content', $settings );
                                                                                ?>
```