# Jquery conflict with WordPress Tinymce

Tags: jquery, tinymce, wordpress

I'm using WordPress TinyMCE editor inside admin page for my plugin.

```
<td id="content_update_editor"><?php the_editor('Write your content here..');?></td>
```

I also have some Ajax call and for that I need jquery to include.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function autopost_getContentData(itemId){

            // get base directory url
            var baseDir = $('#baseDir').val();

            // call to ajax script to get site data
            $.ajax( {
                type: "POST",
                url: baseDir + "/autopost_ajax_actions.php",
                data: "id=" + itemId + "&action=get_content_data",
                success: function(data) {
                    // somework
                }
            });
        }


    </script>
```

When jquery is added, Jquery works fine but the editor got trouble and it does not show the toolbar but when I remove the jquery code, the editor starts working? Any reason of this conflict?Thanks

Comment: I mean, When i remove the jquery code.

Comment: yeah i just got that :) any console errors?

Comment: No, there is no such console error.

Comment: When striped out the jquery resource link, the editor works fine but then jquery stop working.

Comment: which version of tinymce are you using?

Comment: I'm using the default WordPress Tinymce  `the_editor();` and `// add WYSIWUG editor
wp_enqueue_script(array('jquery', 'editor', 'thickbox', 'media-upload'));
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
add_action("admin_head","autopost_load_tiny_mce");`

Comment: See I have an same issue before here is the link that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566673/wordpress-editor-text-tab-design-issue Hope this may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Jquery no conflict may solve your problem

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();      
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: Not working, When striped out the jquery resource link, the editor works fine but then jquery stop working.

Comment: can you give your url to see that, Have you used $.noConflict()? if its fails use `var jq = $.noConflict();` and instead of $ use jq

Comment: I have it at my local machine and yes i added $.noConflict();

Comment: try the second method and follow the order of including script too

Comment: Same problem even after trying your both ways.